# Verify this cfg is finite or not

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

S-> aAb | aBd
A-> ab | Bd | e
B-> ab | d | f

I am getting a loop during CNF conversion but in question it stated that it's a finite language.

Comment: Can you generate infinitely many words?

Comment: actually i am finding difficulty in converting this to CNF

Comment: I suggest forgetting about CNF. You can figure out the finiteness without using CNF.

Answer (score 1):

If we read the productions of $B$ we immediately see that the language generated by $B$ contains exactly three words ($\{ab,d,f\}$).

Hence, the production $A\to Bd$ also generates three words. Considering all the productions of $A$, we can say that $A$ contains at most 1+3+1 words.

Can you now give an upper bound to the number of words of $S$, considering its productions?

Alternatively, note that if we (well-)order the nonterminals as $S > A > B$ we can see that expanding a non terminal with any production causes the appearance of only "smaller" nonterminals. Hence, there is an upper bound to the number of expansions we can perform starting from $S$.